# What would happen to a planet without its core?

Tags: planets, earth-like

What would happen to an Earth-like planet if its core completely and instantly vanished? Would the planet begin to pull in on itself due to asymmetry and the empty space in the middle, or would it begin to fail due to another factor? Or would it remain (relatively) unscathed? If so, for how long?

Comment: (Pure Speculation) - I think the Earth would get destabilized, collapse and it would end up crushed with the Moon into a new planet.    If the Core gets teleported nearby, - the collapse would be immediately subject to the Core's gravitational pull? And just re-crush itself into a new earth again (possibly dragging the Moon out of orbit at the same time into an even bigger earth)

Comment: @2012rcampion he is probably refering to the question before I edited it. It was about teleportation, but I decided to cut to the chase and set it to something more simipiler.

Comment: Inner and outer core?

Comment: Still I maintain my speculation on the Moon's orbit being disturbed : )    Otherwise in any scenario I do think we'd see the planet collapse.

Comment: @Spacemonkey The moon would actually go spinning off into space (or the Sun) due to the reduction in gravity from the Earth.

Comment: The moon's orbit would definitely be disturbed. Whether it escapes depends on how much of the core exactly vanishes. Either way, every living thing on the earth is going to die.

Comment: Seems to me like if the Moon is orbiting away from the sun (around the earth) at the moment the Earth collapses, it would be dragged back faster towards the sun due to the decreased slingshot effect by the Earth's lower mass - thus possibly ending up on a direct collision course with the collapsed earth, not to mention the earth would probably also end being pulled somewhat more by the Moon itself, the resulting Mass/Planet would most likely lose some velocity and see it,s orbit around the Sun change. But yeah. not sure about any of it.

Comment: @Spacemonkey See a [related question](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/6518/3202) to exactly that.

Comment: For a much more interesting outcome (more interesting than "crust sinks into the magma and whole planet becomes a ball of magma without atmosphere, land or any other features) instead of removing the core, replace it, say, with quartz or whatever. Reducing the mass of the planet and removing the iron core but not changing its volume by much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Collapse.

Gravity takes care of this. As soon as you remove the core from the Earth, you have a large void in the middle of it, and a lot of gravity acting straight towards the centre of that void. The void may also be a vacuum - depending on whether you replace the core with air or not - which will accelerate the collapse.

It is worth noting that this is only possible because the mantle is liquid. If it were solid, the spherical shape would hold it together and the Earth would retain its shape.

As Spacemonkey has said, the resulting loss of mass of the Earth *would* disturb the Moon's orbit. I'll go into some basic orbital mechanics to show why and how.

The Moon has a stable orbit around Earth because as its velocity carries it forward, the gravity of the Earth pulls it sideways, resulting in a perpetual circle:

[image: depiction of the forces acting on the Moon]

If the mass of the Earth decreases suddenly, so does the sideways force on the Moon, so it moves more straight - away from Earth. As it does this, the force decreases further, so it moves even further away, and so on:

[image: depiction of the forces acting on the Moon orbiting an Earth of lesser mass]

This is... bad. Not only has everyone *already* died because everything collapsed underneath them, but [scientists predict bad things](http://sciencenordic.com/what-would-we-do-without-moon) if we lose the moon.

---

In short: everyone dies.

Comment: In the diagrams, which way is toward the Sun?

Comment: Actually, being liquid isn't required for collapse. A sphere wouldn't be able to contain a hard vacuum no matter what state it was in. Replacing it with air is a strange assumption, but even then, the pressure is minor compared to the outside. A single point crumbling would cascade a collapse across the whole structure. Perhaps if the remaining inner shell was airtight *and* pressurized with gas, but that's an even more bizarre assumption.

Comment: @Samuel I pretty much agree. Assuming the material on the inner surface of the now-hollow earth wouldn't crumble is similar to assuming you can tunnel through the side of a mountain and the top of your tunnel won't crumble either. Miners always support their tunnel ceilings with posts & cross braces.

Comment: Additionally I think you might be exaggerating the effects regarding the moon. The [inner core is only 1.7% of the Earth's mass](http://solarviews.com/eng/earthint.htm). Even if you're including the outer core, which is a much more significant portion of the mass (both together are 32.5%) a majority of the mass remains. The Moon isn't going anywhere too quickly. Besides, in the solar reference frame, [the Moon tracks the Earth very closely](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/6524/3202).

Comment: @Samuel The Moon *might* settle down into a wider orbit, but it's about an even chance either way - and a wider orbit still brings many of the bad things with it.

Comment: @HDE226868 Any direction since they're for illustrative purposes. I know, I know, the Moon would be attracted to the Sun too... ;)

Comment: @ArtOfCode A wider orbit would bring bad things for an intact and living Earth. It would be the least of Earth's worries in this case.

Comment: @Samuel Aye, that's why the last paragraph of this answer.

Comment: @HDE226868, it's irrelevant which direction is towards the sun. Even if the moon leaves Earth's orbit, it won't go crashing into the sun - the combined Earth-Moon system is still going ~30 km/s, and it's all traveling around the sun. The Moon, meanwhile, is only going 1 km/s relative to Earth. So when the Moon leaves the Earth, it'll end up in some kind of more-elliptical-than-usual orbit (the exact orbit depending on exactly where the Moon is when Earth's core vanishes), but it'll still be going around the sun.

Comment: `scientists predict bad things if we lose the moon.`  Actually, at the very bottom of that article, it explicitly predicts exactly the opposite: if we suddenly lost the moon, it wouldn't be all that bad.

Comment: @Samuel, this is true for most spherical bodies but not all.  Some of the smallest spherical bodies formed a sphere while in their molten state.  As they cooled, their rock hardened.  Some of them might be able to maintain their shape if their cores were removed but this would be a very special case of the smallest spherical bodies in the solar system.

Comment: @Jim2B The question is about planets, and on that scale there is no way a natural formation is going to hold a vacuum.

Comment: I can agree with that :)

Comment: Actually the moon is unlikely to be at escape velocity, it will settle down into a new highly eliptical orbit.

Comment: I can't believe that nobody mentioned this yet... the Earth's mantle *is not liquid*. It's almost entirely solid. The fact that it still moves (in relation to other layers and itself) is a clear example that at those temperatures and pressures, the material isn't anywhere near strong enough to maintain itself against a cavity. This is worse the deeper you go, of course. If you remove the core, all the higher layers will collapse - violently (and if the core is teleported outside, rather than just "disappearing", it will explode violently as it loses the pressure from the outside rock).

Answer (score 5):

### The planet would implode.

You've instantly removed the core. So what's in its place? **Hard vacuum**. There is a [relevant xkcd](https://what-if.xkcd.com/6/) for a similar scenario.

Outside of the core-vacuum is a molten magma. The pressure exerted from the Earth on the other side of that magma is still present and the magma will be blown, violently, into the suddenly empty space. This rapid movement will ripple up to the surface of the Earth along the most fluid paths. This will take about five minutes. Basically, it would be like every volcano erupting, at once, *in reverse*. The entire surface of the Earth would likely experience double digit [Richter scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richter_magnitude_scale) values. The magma rushing into the vacuum would slam into magma coming the other direction at very high velocity and, five minutes later, the shockwave would make all the volcanoes and new fissures on Earth erupt at once, in the normal direction.

This would most certainly be an extinction level event. All life bigger than bacteria would die immediately, probably in the first ten minutes during the collapse. The rest of the life would die during the world wide eruptions and when the atmosphere escapes the Earth's corpse.

The moon would [probably stick around](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/6524/3202) for a little while.

Comment: At the risk of providing a useless comment: I often wonder if / hope that XKCD will be part of this community.

Comment: You wouldn't need to wait for the shock wave. First, after the magma core, all of Earth crust gets sucked down and simultaneously crunched laterally (Earth radius just got smaller, "too big skin on too small ball"), but the moment the drop stops, it would crash hard against the magma core and sink into the magma. Only few airborne bacteria would survive that moment, then would quickly die in convection of overheated air and steam.

Comment: @SF. Yeah, possibly. Though the magma will be imploding faster than freefall. Since the tensile strength isn't great for magma, the surface would be getting down by freefall, only to be met part way down with the shock wave coming back up through the magma.

Comment: @Samuel: Most of the surface would be sucked down by the same force that pulls the magma; only the very outermost layers (~50m?) where air could penetrate would -possibly- tear off and fall at freefall speed (though moist soil, oceans, surface-reaching bedrock would not; deserts would fly in a cloud but oceans would collapse)

Comment: @Samuel yeah, convection of heat from the exposed mantle would finish off whatever the fall did not.

Comment: There wouldn't be *suction* in the manner in which you describe.  Suction is just higher pressure pushing something into lower a lower pressure area.  The force of the mass of the unsupported mantle would be far greater than that of any atmospheric pressure pushing it into the now vacant core.  @Samuel, udder destruction is feeding a cow sticks of dynamite, n'est pas? lol

Comment: @Jim2B Yes, it would be suction. If a magma layer is pulling away from an upper layer there isn't anything to fill that gap, so to do so it would have to create a vacuum, which is a low pressure area. The upper layer having higher than vacuum pressure above it would be blown into that vacuum as quickly as it could form - that's *suction*, n'est pas?

Comment: At time step 1 (instant after core implosion) the lowest slice of mantle has 0 pascals on the lower side and 360 GPa on the other.  This (and its own gravitational acceleration) accelerates the inner slice so it is no longer in contact with the second slice up.  At time step 2, the innermost slice has pressure 0 on top and bottom but slice 2 has 0 pascals on the lower side and 360 GPa on its upper slice.  What I'm saying is that this pressure only acts as an initial acceleration after which the fall is purely ballistic.

Comment: The effect would look very much like a rarefaction / expansion wave of air when (e.g.) a door is opened to vacuum.  Initial acceleration due to pressure followed by ballistic motion as depicted in this image http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/40/Pressure_plot.png/400px-Pressure_plot.png

Comment: This doesn't change the results though.  Everything @Samuel mentioned still happens (fall, compression faulting at every level of the Earth, collision & rebound at the center causing a shock wave to propagate outwards, followed by it blowing off portions of the Earth).  Plus the fall releases tons of potential energy which heats things up and generally kills everything in a most spectacular fashion.