# If Earth were destroyed would that damage the solar system?

Tags: planets, physics, space, aliens

I'm building a new world. In this setting an alien race defeated humanity by blowing up the Earth with a massive plasma weapon. The aliens are interested in the resources of our system: mining and studying it.

If Earth is destroyed, would it damage our solar system?

Comment: hard to say, depends on how much junk is thrown out into the solar system, and it depends what you mean by "damage", would a few chunks of earth hit other planets, probably.  Maybe even the moon might, but it may take hundreds or thousands of years for them to say hit mars or the other planets.  Just depends on how many chunks and what change in orbit they have.  May even wind up with an earth asteroid belt.

Comment: Probably what the Martians did to Phaeton, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phaeton_(hypothetical_planet)

Comment: That depends on how this weapon would work and what do you consider to be "damage" to solar system. Turning Earth into a small debris field that will soon form new Earth would have different impact than, for example, putting debris on collision course with Mars.

Comment: Just be sure that you understand how difficult it is to “blow up” a planet, which is held together by gravity. It would take over one quadrillion of our biggest nuclear warheads, about a trillion tonnes of antimatter, or the entire energy output of the Sun for a week.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to mine materials if they were already in small chunks rather than planet-sized ones? Not sure it would be considered damage from their POV if some other planets got destroyed alongside Earth.

Comment: Massive plasma weapons are only likely to vaporize the surface layers of planet Earth. Goodbye, atmosphere too. This will increase the amount of gas & dust in the solar system. The victorious aliens won't be too inconvenienced in mining the resources of the system.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about the word "destroyed" - what happens exactly, is it fragmented into pieces that fly apart? Does it disappear altogether? Does it become a big pile of rubble that just hangs around where Earth was (in which case gravity would probably just cause it to reform into another - Earth sized planet). Also what do you mean by "damage"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would the sudden destruction of Earth affect other planets within the Solar System?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/6518/how-would-the-sudden-destruction-of-earth-affect-other-planets-within-the-solar)

Comment: Does your definition of "damage" include a planet missing? Then yeah, it is "damaged".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to say **No** at least not in any major kind of way.

The worst case scenario (for the Solar System) is that Earth is exploded into little bits which are sent flying everywhere - at a speed faster than their collective escape velocity.

The only one to be dramatically affected will be the Moon which will lose its partner, and will enter its own orbit of the Sun, and will bear the brunt of the shrapnel.

The orbits of the other planets - maybe Mars and Venus anyway might be affected slightly also, but it's not like they have eco-systems that can be destroyed by climate change.

As for the pieces, you have to remember the old axiom that Space is big, there's plenty of room in the Solar System. They will be no different from any of the other millions of pieces of rock in the Solar System. They will all find their own orbits depending on their trajectory after the explosion. Sure some of them *might* hit a planet (or probably will hit the Moon) but they will be no different from the rocks floating through space that strike the various planets from time to time, and it could take millenia for that to happen.

The aliens can wait a few days (although what's a day any more?) for the debris to pass the Moon if they want to use it, map the velocity of the pieces using their highly advanced alien technology and keep themselves safely out of the way while they mine the other planets.

**Edit** 
Just a note to add that the aliens now have access to the Earth's iron core, so if iron is one of the resources they are mining, they'd probably collect it as it flies through space, further reducing the potential damage to the other planets.

Answer (score 1):

Solar system wouldn't be destroyed, but it would be altered for sure:

- Scattered earth pieces could have an effect on other planets or satellites (either by crashing on them or by passing closely and pulling them gravitationally).
- The moon would be left wandering the space, and may cause the same effect.
- Other planets may be moved slightly due the variation of the gravity they percieved from (now disappeared) earth.